# Trouble RIGHT JOIN-ing multiple tables to one central table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am attempting to join several tables to one central table in an append query. My code is as follows:

```
INSERT INTO tblVolume ( [P/N], Mobility, VolumeDate, Volume )
SELECT tblPartNumber.[P/N], tblMobility.Mobility, tblVolume.Date, tblVolume.Volume
FROM tblVolume 
RIGHT JOIN tblPartNumber
ON tblVolume.[P/N]=tblPartNumber.PartNumber_ID
RIGHT JOIN tblMobility
ON tblVolume.Mobility=tblMobility.Mobility_ID;
```

I want to continue this for one more table, but have stopped here because I can't even get this to work.

The error message says I am missing an operator. Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: If you are using microsoft access, it isn't happy when join order isn't forced by enclosing joins in parentheses.

Comment: which table is your primary table? I find it easier to start with the primary table and use `left join` otherwise you would write it backwards using `right join` and your last table is your primary table.

Comment: tblVolume is my primary table. I used RIGHT JOIN because I want all records from the non-primary tables.

Comment: left join and right join do the same thing just in a different direction, are you looking for a `full outer join`? https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/joins.php

Comment: Ultimately, I want all available records so that I can append new records that are not yet in the Volume table yet. (ex: a new volume for the next month). Even so, I tried replacing RIGHT JOIN with LEFT JOIN and FULL OUTER JOIN. Always the same error

Comment: I don't think that the problem is just in the missing operator, what are you trying to do will lead to duplicate rows in tblVolume, also may insert unrelated data in some rows.

Comment: What is the rest of the error message? It should tell you where you which expression is missing an operator?

Comment: Given that you describe a "central table", that would usually imply that there is a always a record in the central table that shares the relevant ID with the right-joined table. In which case you should use `inner join`, which will return rows for all the non-central tables even if they're "sharing" the matched record in the central table.